# Image comparison slider with pure css

Tags: css, email, slider, html-email

I'm trying to create an image comparison slider for a html email I'm creating. As it's an email I can't use scripts, I've found this great example using pure css: http://lea.verou.me/2014/07/image-comparison-slider-with-pure-css/ But it doesn't work on mobile. Has anyone got any ideas on how I could adapt this example to get it working on mobile please? Or any other ideas on creating a pure css image comparison slider, which would work on at least some mobile browsers.

Comment: Works on desktop as its click and drag. On mobiles it tap, which means you don't have click or you might need to hold the tap down for a few seconds before it moves? The link you provided doesnt work on Chrome on Android. (just tried)

Comment: Ok thanks, it was Chrome on Android I was testing it on. Do you know why it won't work on Chrome Android?

Comment: Like i said above. Its the difference between click and tap (desktop vs mobile). Not sure if there is a pure CSS comparison slider for mobile.